# PHP array changes won't store

Tags: php, cmd

Why doesn't my array get updated.
Let's say I store 2 items Shoes and Shirt, and I get something like this.

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [item_id] => 1
        [item_name] => shoes
        [item_price] => 10
        [item_quantity] => 10
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [item_id] => 2
        [item_name] => Shirt
        [item_price] => 5
        [item_quantity] => 5
    )

)
```

And that's fine. But if I pass 1 and 4 to getItem function it echoes out remaining items as it should, 6 in this case, but if I check the $inventoryItems array it still says there are 10 Shoes. And if I pass again 1 and 4 it will give the same result, 6, but it should return 2.

```
class Inventory{
public $inventoryItems = [];

public function storeItem($item){
    $this->inventoryItems[] = [
        'item_id' => $item->itemId,
        'item_name' => $item->itemName,
        'item_price' => $item->itemPrice,
        'item_quantity' => $item->itemQuantity
    ];

}

public function inventoryList(){
    print_r($this->inventoryItems);
}

public function getItem($itemId, $itemQuantity){
    foreach($this->inventoryItems as $inventoryItem){
        if($inventoryItem['item_id'] === $itemId && $inventoryItem['item_quantity'] > 0){ 
            $inventoryItem['item_quantity'] -= $itemQuantity;
            echo $inventoryItem['item_quantity'] . ' ' . 
                $inventoryItem['item_name'] . " remaining. \n";
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($this->inventoryItems as $inventoryItem){
```

is creating a *copy* of each `inventoryItem` and storing it in `$inventoryItem`.  You can change it to:

```
foreach($this->inventoryItems as &$inventoryItem){
```

to get a reference to the inventory item, and then the changes will happen in the original.